# Is there a way to simplify the functions and check all the input box at once and not one by one

Tags: javascript, date, asp-classic

I have a javascript function that validate the input of dates. Dates input has to be DD/MM/YYYY. I am trying to stop user from entering DD/MM/YY. 
When I click the submit button of the form during post-back, I am calling the function. I put onsubmit the function with a return in the form tag. I check one by one for every date input box and if there is an error, I will return false. This will only check each box one by one. 
However, I wish to check all the date input box at once and list out all the wrong ones instead of one by one, I also wish to stop the postback if there is an error found, how can I accomplish this? Please help.

I put the function during onsubmit and the form tag.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="tmemply_det.asp" method="post" onsubmit="return validatedt();">
```

I have 5 dates input and here is one of them

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Date Join : </label>
    <div id="div_dt_join" class="col-sm-5 col-lg-3">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input id="dt_join" name="dt_join" value="<%=dt_join%>" type="text" class="form-control" date-picker>
       <div class="input-group-addon">
          <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
       </div>
      </div>
      <span id="errdt_join" class="help-block"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The javascript function

```
function validatedt(){

    var input = document.getElementById("dt_join").value;
    var pattern =/^([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{4})$/;

    if (pattern.test(input)==false){
        alert("Date Join format is incorrect, please key in DD/MM/YYYY");
        document.getElementById('div_dt_join').className += ' has-error'
        document.getElementById("errdt_join").innerHTML = "Please key in DD/MM/YYYY" 
        return false;
        }   

    var input = document.getElementById("dt_confirm").value;
    var pattern =/^([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{4})$/;

    if (input.length!=0 && pattern.test(input)==false){
        alert("Date Confirm format is incorrect, please key in DD/MM/YYYY");
        document.getElementById('div_dt_confirm').className += ' has-error'
        document.getElementById("errdt_confirm").innerHTML = "Please key in DD/MM/YYYY" 
        return false;
        }  

    var input = document.getElementById("dt_resign").value;
    var pattern =/^([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{4})$/;

    if (input.length!=0 && pattern.test(input)==false){
        alert("Date Resign format is incorrect, please key in DD/MM/YYYY");
        document.getElementById('div_dt_resign').className += ' has-error'
        document.getElementById("errdt_resign").innerHTML = "Please key in DD/MM/YYYY" 
        return false;
        }  

    var input = document.getElementById("dt_DOB").value;
    var pattern =/^([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{4})$/;

    if (pattern.test(input)==false){
        alert("Date of Birth format is incorrect, please key in DD/MM/YYYY");
        document.getElementById('div_dt_DOB').className += ' has-error'
        document.getElementById("errdt_DOB").innerHTML = "Please key in DD/MM/YYYY" 
        return false;
        }

    var input = document.getElementById("dt_WorkPEx").value;
    var pattern =/^([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{4})$/;

    if (input.length!=0 && pattern.test(input)==false){
        alert("Work Permit Expiry Date format is incorrect, please key in DD/MM/YYYY");
        document.getElementById('div_dt_WorkPEx').className += ' has-error'
        document.getElementById("errdt_WorkPEx").innerHTML = "Please key in DD/MM/YYYY" 
        return false;
        }     
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loops are your friends.

```
function validatedt(){
  var success = true;
  var inputData = ['Join', 'Confirm', 'Resign', 'of Birth', 'Work Permit Expiry'];
  for (var i = 0; i < inputData.length; i++) {
    var key = inputData[i].toLowerCase();
    var msg = "Date " + inputData[i];

    //Deal with edge cases where naming doesn't follow convention
    if (inputData[i] === 'of Birth') {
      key = 'DOB';
    }
    else if (inputData[i] === 'Work Permit Expiry') {
      key = 'WorkPEx';
      msg = inputData[i];
    }

    var input = document.getElementById("dt_" + key).value;
    var pattern =/^([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{4})$/;

    if (pattern.test(input)==false){
      alert(msg + " format is incorrect, please key in DD/MM/YYYY");
      document.getElementById('div_dt_' + key).className += ' has-error'
      document.getElementById("errdt_" + key).innerHTML = "Please key in DD/MM/YYYY" 
      success = false;
    }
  }
  return success;
}
```

In order to update multiple errors, we do not return false straight away. Instead we store a variable "success" with a value of true, so it will return true if everything is okay. If there is any error, it will return false, as we change the variable when we detect the error. We only return once we have finished checking everything.

Comment: Hi OwChallie, thank you so much for your quick reply, I have tried your code but it still checks input by input. Is there a way to check all the inputs from one page at one go and prompt those that are incorrect? In other words is if there is 2 incorrect inputs, I can straight away prompt the user both the incorrect inputs instead of one after another?